# AngularJS pretty URLs does work only partialy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, angular-ui-router

> ### EDIT: Problem in nutshell
>
> Angular routes break after adding more then one parameter to the URL when using hasbang method.

I have a problem with AngularJS ui-routing, for some reason the routing works only partialy when I want to use "pretty URLs", I looked up many tutorials and threads on these forums, but I just can't find any solution for this.

I have an app just like this one: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router,
the only change I made is, that I added `<base href="/">` in `<head>` of **index.html** file.

By default it works fine, but in the url there is always hastag so the url looks like

```
http://ag-routing.lc/#/home
```

but I want it to look like this

```
http://ag-routing.lc/home
```

before you start downvoting me that this is a duplicate, here comes the problem:

On every forum I looked at, this is supposed to be the solution, paste it in your config and magic will happen.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

This is how my app.js looks like with the hasbang code

```
// app.js
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider

// HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
    })
......
```

Now the **# is gone**, but if I refresh the page, I get a weird results or 404. So again I looked up for a solution and found out, that you have to add this code to **.htaccess** ([source](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode))

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Yay, now it works with refresh and direct links as well, but here is **the real problem for which I can't find a solution:**

When I hit refresh on page

```
http://ag-routing.lc/home
```

It works fine, but when I go directly (or by refresh) on page

```
http://ag-routing.lc/home/paragraph
```

it breaks, simply, second "/" will just nuke the page from orbit, it stops working and I have no idea why, the only thing I found out is, that when I open the console in chrome I get really weird results such as:

```
app.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular.js:3660 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate   module routerApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'routerApp' is not available! You either  misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure  that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/nomod?p0=routerApp
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js:78:12
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js:1531:17
at ensure (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js:1456:38)
at module (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js:1529:14)
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js:3632:22
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js:304:11)
at loadModules (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js:3626:5)
at createInjector (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js:3566:11)
at doBootstrap (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js:1301:20)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=routerApp&p1=Error…trap%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.2.13%2Fangular.js%3A1301%3A20)
```

and the biggest mindblown is, that when I open **app.js** in resources, the **js code is gone and it's replaced with the HTML from index.html** ಠ_ಠ

Any help appreciated and sorry for bad English...

*By the way, the problem persists when I use ng-route instead of ui-route.*

**EDIT:** I found out that when I set the **locationProvider** to **false** and hit refresh, the url turns into this thing, which seems to be wrong:

```
http://ag-routing.lc/about#/about
```

Comment: have you checked this part of the ui-router FAQ? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-my-assets-and-templates-are-not-loading

Comment: also, do you have the DocumentRoot and Directory set properly in the apache config?

Comment: @M21B8 Tried to remove the base tag, but it still doesn't work... and yes i believe the apache is set up properly, my vhosts DocumentRoot is pointing into the folder with my app.
<VirtualHost *:80>   
DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\angular\uiRouter" 
ServerName ag-routing.lc
</VirtualHost>

Comment: I believe the rewrite is supposed to be inside that VirtualHost declaration. make sure the config looks like the one detailed here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: @M21B8 Unfortunatly that did not work either.

Comment: Can't help any further I'm afraid, we have no idea what our context roots are in production, so we had to drop html5 mode for now :(

Comment: @M21B8 Thanks for trying to help, I finally found a solution,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of googling and putting things together, I finally stumbled upon an answer, that makes this work. The mistake I made is that I used absolute paths for my assets and links, which is wrong, you **have to use relative paths**, for example:

I had paths set up like this:

```
<!-- index.html file -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="assets/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
<a href="about">About</a>
```

Notice the missing "/" at the beggining of each link, that's the catch, because, if you want to use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` you have to set up a `<base href="/">` to make it work and now you have to refer to it.

Simply, to make it work you have to make sure all your links start with **"/"** symbol.

Like this:

```
<!-- index.html file -->
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/assets/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

To make the hasbang work even with refresh on page you have to **set up .htaccess properly** as well.

This is how my .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /#!/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

Notice that I use "/#!/", you can set that up in angular routes where the location provider is, like this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```